# Как запретить скролл страницы при наведении на div?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть `div` с фиксированным позиционированием и `overflow: auto`.
В блоке прокручивается текст колесом мыши. После того, как весь текст в блоке
прокручен, начинает скролиться страница. Как запретить прокрутку `body`,
пока курсор находится в `div-е`?

Comment: меня в таких вопросах всегда интересует ЗАЧЕМ? вот чем оно мешает? простите за оффтоп.

Comment: Если бы не нужно было, наверное бы не спрашивал.

Comment: ну а ответить сложно? вы тут ждете от людей какой-то ответ, а сами не можете?) ну интересно же, в каких случаях это НАДО

Comment: Суть в следующем. В диве меню по одностраничнику. При клике на определенный пункт страница прокручивается. И при прокрутке страницы вручную в диве прокручиваются пункты меню, чтобы активный пункт был в самом верху видимой области. Ну и получается, что при прокрутке страницы js-функция будет крутить текст в диве.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно при наведении на `div` ставить значение `overflow` у `body` в `hidden`.

```js
$('#div').on('mouseenter', function (event) {
   $("body").css("overflow","hidden"); 
}).on('mouseleave',  function(){
   $("body").css("overflow","auto");
});
```

```css
body{
    height:1500px;
}

#div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background: #333;
    overflow: auto
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div">
</div>
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/gkfobs3a/)

### Добавлено:

вот такое решение предлагается [коллегами с англ. версии](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571370/jquery-disable-scroll-when-mouse-over-an-absolute-div/7571867#7571867). Правда, как и заметил @Rolandius имеются проблемы с совместимостью.

```
$('#div').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var scrollTo = null;
    if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
        scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
    }
    else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
        scrollTo = 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;
    }
    if (scrollTo) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).scrollTop(scrollTo + $(this).scrollTop());
    }
});
```

Пример в работе: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kixkix/gkfobs3a/1/)

Comment: А есть ли другой вариант? Этот вариант я рассматривал, он не подходит, так как сдвигается контент. Но даже если добавлять margin для body, выглядит не очень хорошо. Нужно оставить полосу прокрутки.

Comment: Прокрутка документа может ещё активироваться стрелками на клавиатуре и пробелом, да и само `DOMMouseScroll` [не везде](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMMouseScroll) работает. Слишком сложно получится.

Comment: Нужно ограничить прокрутку только колесиком.

Comment: @ВикторПавлов обновил ответ

Answer (score 0):

Для меня единственным рабочим способом оказался следующий:

```js
var scrollEvents = ['wheel', 'mousewheel']

function freezeScroll(){
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        elem = arguments[i];
        let func = preventScrollEventFunc(elem);
        let options = {passive: false};
        $(elem).on('mouseenter', function(){
            onWheel(window, func, options);
        }).on('mouseleave', function(){
            removeOnWheel(window, func);
        });
    }
}
// Отменить скролл страницы, если элемент selector прокручен до упора
function preventScrollEventFunc(selector){
    let elem = $(selector);
    function preventScroll(e){
        let offset = e.wheel || e.wheelDelta;
        let crossingUpper = elem.scrollTop() == 0 && offset > 0;
        let crossingDown = (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() ==
            elem[0].clientHeight && offset < 0);
        if (crossingUpper || crossingDown){
            e.preventDefault()
        }
    }
    return preventScroll;
}
// Повесить обработчик func для событий wheel и mousewheel у elem
function onWheel(elem, func, options){
    options = options || {};
    scrollEvents.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
        elem.addEventListener(item, func, options);
    });
}
// Убрать обработчик func для событий wheel и mousewheel у elem
function removeOnWheel(elem, func, options){
    options = options || {};
    scrollEvents.forEach(function(item, i, arr){
        elem.removeEventListener(item, func, options);
    });
}


$(document).ready(function (){

freezeScroll('#div', '#div2', #div3', '#div...');

});
```

При наведении мыши на элемент, вешаем на окно обработчик событий wheel и mousewheel, который предотвращает событие прокрутки, если элемент прокручен до предела (так как следующим прокрутиться уже не элемент, а сама страница). При выходе за пределы элемента убираем обработчики.